# Using pre populated database blackberry webworks/phonegap?

Tags: cordova, blackberry, phonegap-plugins, blackberry-webworks

I created an app using **Phonegap** for android and blackberry, 
for android I used a pre populated db.

I want to do the same for blackberry.
I have seen this question asked at many places but haven't found a solution.

please tell me if using a pre populated db with blackberry is possible or not. also suggest some alternatives if not possible. I have a large amount of data and it would be ideal if I could use the pre populated db

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: I was doing research on this myself and came across an answer here on stackoverflow. You can check it out [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738163/blackberry-attach-pre-populated-sqlite-database)